# Как вызвать функцию из функции в php?

Tags: php

Есть условие:

```
$mycalc = new MyCalculator(12, 6);
echo $mycalc->add();
echo $mycalc->add()->divideBy(9);
```

как вызвать из функции другую функцию? постоянно выдаёт фаталку.

Comment: А эту "фаталку" можете показать в вопросе?) Ну и заодно код класса MyCalculator

Comment: у фаталки есть сообщение,  в которм написано что не так и на какой строчке...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызвывают функцию из функции вот так:

```
function test1() {
    test2();
}

function test2() {
}
```

Тоже самое можно спроецировать на методы.

---

А вот чтобы вызывать методы цепочкой друг за другом **одного и того же класса** надо чтобы предыдущий метод возвращал `$this`

---

Чтобы можно было делать так:

```
echo $mycalc->add();
echo $mycalc->add()->divideBy(9);
```

то есть и выводить результат вычисления метода и чтобы метод был звеном цепочки, можно сделать внутреннее свойство с результатом вычислений и все операции делайте с ней в методах. Возвращайте `$this`. А также в классе добавить/переопределить метод **[__toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)**  который будет возвращать значение этой внутренней переменной

Comment: Как поступить если у меня таких 4 метода и они могут вызвать любые другие 4 метода?

Comment: Вы же прочитали последнее предложение в ответе?

Comment: Мне помимо цепочки методов нужно вызывать и обычные методы типа $mycalc->add(); но при return $this появляется fatal error

Comment: не правда. оно не может появляться, если только ещё где-то как-то не так код используется........ и у fatal error есть чёткие конкретные тексты ошибок. Надо их читать и переводить что не так

Comment: Зачем мне врать? Вод код с ошибкой. class Test{ 
 private $num1, $num2, $answer; 
 
 public function __construct($num1, $num2){ 
 $this->num1 = $num1; 
 $this->num2 = $num2; 
 } 
 
 public function add(){ 
 $this->answer = $this->num1 + $this->num2; 
 return $this; 
 }  
 
 
 
 public function divideBy($number){ 
 
 return $this->answer / $number; 
 } 
} 
 
 
 
$mycalc = new Test(12, 6); 
echo $mycalc->add();
echo $mycalc->add()->divideBy(9);

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class src\Test could not be converted to string in "echo $mycalc->add();"

Comment: Логично. Вы делаете echo для результата выполнения метода. Вот он и не понимает зачем вы класс к строке хотите привести......... заведите приватное свойство с результатом  в классе и все операции делайте с ней в методах, а потом в методе getResult()  возвращайте его........

Comment: Да, но тогда решение задачи не будет подходить её условию, так как в примере указано так, как я написал в вопросе.

Comment: Такого не бывает. Метод не может одновременно и вернуть значение высиления и быть звеном в цепочке.  Единственное, опять же, как я описал: сделать внутреннее свойство и в классе добавить/переопределить метод **[__toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)**  который будет возвращать значение этой переменной.... то есть вместо `getResult`  будет `__toString`